# Manullay close iOS gallery in Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

Can we close forcefully iOS gallery if its open using titanium ?

I need close the iOS gallery if the application goes to background to foreground.In the documentation i don't any such method or event.So making sure here by asking.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked recently (by you?) on the Appcelerator JIRA. https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-5647

It is possible on iOS to do this using Hyperloop. If something similar exists natively on Android too then that can also be implemented through hyperloop

Code as proposed in that ticket.

```
var TiApp = require('Titanium/TiApp');
TiApp.app().hideModalControllerAnimated(TiApp.getController().topPresentedController, true);
```

Comment: Yes it was asked by me if somebody needs this and searching in stackoverlflow . **Hans** replied on that too & created new Ticket. Below is the link.Basically Ti.Media.hideCamera() also works.So no need to write hyperloop for this atleast. But thanks to **you &
 hans** for replying.[https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-25846]